# About autoresizing mask

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, autoresizingmask

If I have a `superview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,200);` and a `subview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)`, subview has flexiable width and height, I think when superview's frame changes to `(0,0,150,150)`, then subview's frame should change to `(0, 0, 75, 75)`. But it's not.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

UIView * view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:view1];

UIView * view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
view2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[view1 addSubview:view2];

view1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150);
[self printRect:view2.frame];
}

- (void) printRect:(CGRect)rect
{
NSLog(@"%0.1f, %0.1f, %0.1f, %0.1f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
}
```

Output:

```
0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0
```

And when superview's frame changes to (0,0,100,100), subview's frame will become (0,0,0,0)

Why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your line of code with mine as u forgot `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`

```
  view2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Comment: Thanks man. I add UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin it's right now. Sorry I used to think add UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin means fix left position.. I read the doc, it's alright now..

Answer (score 0):

in your code , `view2` has fixed margins, which from top clockwise to left is (0, 100, 100, 0), this explain your `view2`'s autoresizing behaivor. your `view2`'s height and width wouldn't change only if you enlarge `view1`. so you should add `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` to your `view2`'s autoresziing mask